# PHP expression evaluating to wrong (?) value

Tags: php

Why does the variable `$strange` evaluates to `true` in the following snippet?

```
$strange = true and false;
var_dump($strange); // true
```

Comment: I tested on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ with some of these answers; ALL of them return `bool(false)`.

Comment: @zyboxinternational It's not what I see: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32dd625e6e31e7eb281e43b8c5ead05f8b865553

Comment: You have `short-circuit` operator (as I evidenced in my answer). It seems we have someone here who likes downvote all answer with no idea!!!!

Comment: @yaa110 True. As I was editing my answer the vote count went to 0, then when I finished editing it was back down to `-1`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`and` is a low-[precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) version of `&&`.

```
$strange = true and false;
```

is equivalent to

```
($strange = true) and false;
```

You want

```
$strange = (true and false);
```

or the more appropriate

```
$strange = true && false;
```

`and` and `or` are best reserved when preceding a flow control statement like `break` or `return`.

```
foo()
   or throw new Exception('foo() returned an error.');
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's a problem, let me know what it is so I can fix it.

Comment: I guess there's some serial downvoting going on here.

Comment: Someone is downvoting everyone. Dunno why.

Answer (score 0):

`and` and `or` in PHP have a LOWER operator precedence then `&&` and `||`. Your code is being evaluated as

```
($strange = true) and false;
```

These two would have worked:

```
$strange = true && false;
$strange = (true and false);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is executed then and its 
// value is and'd with the results of the assignment. 
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;
```

The above example is taken straight from there, and matches your issue exactly.

Comment: not ignored. just being parsed/executed differently than OP expected.

Comment: That is copied and pasted straight from the docs. Not saying you're wrong, just who should I trust if I can't trust them?

Comment: More like badly phrased. it's not ignored. It is executed, but since the result of the `and` isn't assigned anywhere, it's the equivalent of a no-op.

Comment: Please don't simply copy code from external sites, please EXPLAIN. Your edit still doesn't satisfy the 'don't copy code with no explanation' requirement of the Stack Overflow Question Requirements.

Comment: I have updated the comment to hopefully be closer in line with whats really going on.  @zyboxinternational The explanation is in the comment, and I believe copying examples from the documentation is helpful in this case.

Comment: Still doesn't... if the page changes or is removed, your answer will become invalid since it has no explanation.

Comment: @smerny Yes, but it STILL doesn't have an explanation. Suppose I'm a newbe to PHP (which I kind of am) and I'm looking for an answer to this, and the external page goes down or is removed. How am I supposed to know how the example works (without searching it externally)?

Comment: @smerny Doesn't matter, this answer doesn't have an explanation.

Comment: @zyboxinternational, I would consider "The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is executed then and its value is and'd with the results of the assignment. Acts like: (($h = true) and false)" an ample explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, but this seems to be an issue with simple logic...
The expression `var_dump($strange);` evaluates and outputs the ***first*** argument.

Comment: backwards. `&&` is a HIGHER precedence version of `and`. Your code WILL output `false`, not true.

Comment: Whoops, well I did say I'm no PHP expert ;). Fixed.

Comment: @MarcB You realise that EVERY answer on this question so far is incorrect, including mine, right? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d519df344ad0f1c8bd331ff6a312c790cb2090a

Comment: Realised that they didn't want a 'correct code', they just wanted an explanation on WHY this happens.

Comment: Reason for the downvote now, I gave the correct answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I'm assuming the person who downvoted did so before you edited and isn't paying attention anymore... but even so, you just reiterate **what** is happening, but you don't say **why**.

Comment: @smerny A 'why' it's happening isn't required, and I've already put that.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) says:

```
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

And

```
// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;
```

So the `false` will be ignored.

Comment: `and` will only short-circuit if the first operand is false.

Comment: yes, as others pointed out... The question has nothing to do with short-circuiting.